# How do I check if nested dictionary has a value of a specific type in Python?

Tags: python

I want to know how I can check if a dictionary with key-value pairs, where the values can be of any python type that contains my custom object.

Lets say object is called MyObject and I have a dictionary.

```
{
   "test1": MyObject()
   "test2": [MyObject(), MyObject()]
   "test3": {"some_key": MyObject()]
   "test4": {"some_key": [MyObject()]
   "test5": (MyObject(), MyObject()) # tuple
   "test6": {MyObject(), MyObject()} # set
   "test7": {"some_key1": {"some_key2": {"some_key3": MyObject()}}}
   ....
}
```

I want to be able to check if any of these values are or contain an instance of my custom object. Is this possible?

I Have tried:

```
def contains_object(d):
   for k,v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, MyObject):
         return True
      elif isinstance(v, (list, set, tuple)):
         for i in v:
            if isinstance(i, MyObject):
               return True
      elif isinstance(v, dict):
         for a, b in v.items():
            if isinstance(b, MyObject):
               return True
   return False
```

How do I simplify the above solution. It should return a boolean for whether or not the dictionary has any value that contains MyObject.

Comment: I have updated the code I tried. I'm sure there is a more simple solution.

Comment: ... recursion ...

Comment: You can try to define a recursive function to achieve your goal. Another trickery way is to do regex matching in string `repr(d)` (not recommended)

Comment: There is not a more simple solution, but did you want your function to find instances in more difficult situation, say where your `dict` just contains the deeply nested instance like under key `"test7"`? Your current code won't find that.

Comment: recursion solves the deeply nested case of `"test7"`, but it can fail if `d` contains itself (cyclic reference)

Comment: Yes, I would require a solution for a very deep dictionary, like "test7" @quamrana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive approach that allows you to navigate any possible nesting within your dictionary.

The following code will do that. It will print the key that's associated with the value matching the custom class. If the custom class instance is within an iterable, the associated key will only be reported once.

```
class MyObject:
    ...


_dict = {
   "test1": MyObject(),
   "test2": [MyObject(), MyObject()],
   "test3": {"some_key": MyObject()},
   "test4": {"some_key": [MyObject()]},
   "test5": (MyObject(), MyObject()),
   "test6": {MyObject(), MyObject()},
   "test7": {"some_key1": {"some_key2": {"some_key3": MyObject()}}}
}

def parse(d):
    key = None
    def _parse(d):
        nonlocal key
        if isinstance(d, MyObject):
            print(key)
            return True
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            for key, v in d.items():
                _parse(v)
        elif isinstance(d, (list, set, tuple)):
            for v in d:
                if _parse(v) is True:
                    break
    _parse(d)

parse(_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
test1
test2
some_key
some_key
test5
test6
some_key3
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work in most cases or at least serve as a good starting point for further expansion. It is based on simple recursion as suggested in the comments

```
def contains_target_type(element, target_type):
    if isinstance(element, target_type):
        return True
    elif isinstance(element, dict):
        for value in element.values():
            if contains_target_type(value, target_type):
                return True
    elif isinstance(element, (list, set, tuple)):
        for value in element:
            if contains_target_type(value, target_type):
                return True
    return False
```

You can call it like:

```
target_type = MyObject
flag = contains_target_type(dict_test_data, target_type)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify the code such like this:

```
def check_for_custom_object(data):
    if isinstance(data, MyObject):
        # do something with MyObject
    
    elif isinstance(data, (list, set, tuple)):
        for item in data:
            check_for_custom_object(item)
        
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for value in data.values():
            check_for_custom_object(value)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).